# Can't acces swagger server into docker container

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, connexion

I have a swagger server api in python that I can run on my pc and easily access to the user interface via web. I'm now trying to run this API into a docker container and place it into a remote server. After the doing the 'docker run' command int the remote server all seems to be working fine but when I try to connect I got a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED response. The funny thing is that if I enter into the container the swagger server is working and answer my requests.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
MAINTAINER Me
ADD . /myprojectdir
WORKDIR /myprojectdir
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "chmod 777 {start.sh,stop.sh,restart.sh,test.sh}"]
```

Here are my commands to build/run:

```
sudo docker build -t mycontainer .
sudo docker run -d -p 33788:80 mycontainer ./start.sh
```

Here is the start.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $'\r' >> log/server_log_`date +%Y%m`.dat
python3 -m swagger_server >> log/server_log_`date +%Y%m`.dat  2>&1
```

And the **main**.py of the swagger server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion
from .encoder import JSONEncoder


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'A title'})
    app.run(port=80, threaded=True, debug=False)
```

Does anyone know why I can't acces to 'myremoteserver:33788/myservice/ui' and what to change for solving it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out the solution. It's needed to tell the flask server of connexion to run on 0.0.0.0 so that not only local connections are allowed and to change in the swagger.yaml the url with the name of the server where the docker container is located

```
app.run(port=80, threaded=True, debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Hi, I am running swagger with .net application and getting same behaviour.
any workaround for that?